# Hive query HBase so slow

Tags: mapreduce, hbase, hive

I want to use Hive to query the data which is HBase table, like:

```
100         column=cf1:val, timestamp=1379536809907, value=val_100
```

And I type the following command in hive:

```
select * from hbase_table where value = 'val_100';
```

I believe everything has been set up. When I type the above command, it shows me like this:

```
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Starting Job = job_201309031344_0024, Tracking URL =        http://namenode:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201309031344_0024
Kill Command = /usr/libexec/../bin/hadoop job  -kill job_201309031344_0024
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 1; number of reducers: 0
2013-09-18 14:45:53,815 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-09-18 14:46:54,654 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-09-18 14:47:55,449 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-09-18 14:48:56,193 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
2013-09-18 14:49:56,990 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
```

Why the map task is always 0%? What's wrong with it? Does any place which I do not configure?

I find the error in datanode log file :

```
2013-09-18 15:18:27,415 INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: 
Opening socket connection to server datanode2/192.168.1.97:2181. 
Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)

2013-09-18 15:18:27,417 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: 
Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket 
connection and attempting reconnect java.net.ConnectException: 
Connection refused at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) 
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:692)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:350) 
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1068)
```

Comment: Is is stopped forever?Or running too slow?How much data do you have and how many nodes?

Comment: It is stopped for more than 5 minutes...so I kill it. It is only one line data in Hbase like above

Comment: Actually it might be too slow...because it keeps showing map = 0% at some time...

Comment: But is must be something wrong...only one line data to process

Comment: Anything interesting in the TT logs?

Comment: I didn't find error in hive.log and http://namenode:50030/jobdetails.jsp?jobid=job_201309031344_0026

Comment: It just keeps showing me map = 0%

Comment: @user2597504 Did you check if Zookeeper is up and running? (e.g: netstat -ntulp | grep 2181) You might also have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10188889/hbase-connection-refused